# Specific network card configuration on vm with vmware

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware

I need to configure a vm (fedora) in vmware workstation statically configuring its virtual network card to use physical wifi card rather than ethernet card. I'm going to use both physical cards at the same time on host system (eth for work, wifi for vm) Host OS win11 Guest OS fedora vmware version workstation 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm going to use both physical cards at the same time on host system
> (eth for work, wifi for vm)

For WMware Workstation V17 (I use this) you cannot pass through the hardware wifi card.  VMware Workstation (or Player) does not do this.

You need a Wireless USB card.  Now in the VMware menu, you can use passthrough for the USB card, and then configure the USB card in Fedora.

I use a Panda Wireless card, and I configure and use the card in both Ubuntu and Kali.

My Host machine (Windows 11) has its own host wireless card.

Comment: Unexpected for me but thanks for this info, i’ll buy an external wifi. Is there some specific reason for this limitation in vmware?

Comment: Workstation products like VMware and Virtualbox do not do this.  Bare metal hypervisors like VMware ESX and I think bare metal Hyper-V can pass through host hardware.